# Reading file in Python goes into infinite loop

Tags: python

I have a file that has the following contents:

```
a  
b  
c  
d
```

I'm reading this in Python using the following code:

```
f = open('foo.txt')
w = f.readline()

while w is not '' :
  print w
  w = f.readline()
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

> if f.readline() returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached

Why then do I go into an infinite loop?

Comment: I figured out the issue. Changing the while condition to `w != ''` makes it work fine. I'd still like to know why `is not` causes an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't go into an infinite loop with that code.

Comment: Eric, that's interesting. I go into an infinite loop running on Ubuntu 12.10 / 12.04, Python 2.7.3. I tried this on two different systems, and was able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I think @FatalError's answer is correct; I'm on Windows 7 (Py 2.7). Perhaps some optimization is making them into the same object.

Comment: Don't write `while w is not '' :`, just write `while w:`

Comment: Get rid of the `readline` and just use `for w in f:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `is` operator tests if two references reference *exactly the same object*. In this case, you want an equality check as you noted.

The infinite loop happened because although it returned `''`, it was a different instance of `str`.  Different instance, but same value.

Python may or may not choose as an optimization to resuse an existing `str` object (they are immutable, after all).  You should not depend on this type of behavior in general, however, unless the documentation specifically mentions otherwise (like for `None` as it's the one and only instance of `NoneType`).

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting.

If you replace

> while w is ''

with

> while w != ''

the code would run successfully.

This means that readline() returns a new instance of the empty string, instead of returning the global one which you get when you execute

```
s = ''
t = ''
assert s is t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
f = open('foo.txt')

while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
  read_data = f.read()
f.closed
```

It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks.

Refer to this link: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html